# how to create a database in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm creating a barber shop database which revolves around the idea of master table and child tables. In the products table I've to display tax (money format) with some condition on the column of master table. A foreign key is added later on from the master table to child table on "tax" column. How exactly should I write that?

Comment: Come on. Just Google how to make a database in SQL Server.  Its not hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this example would help you

```
 USE COSTUMERENTAL;

    CREATE TABLE dbo.CATEGORY  -- should always specify schema
    (
        CATEGORY_ID       CHAR(5)    PRIMARY KEY, -- can't be two data types
        CATEGORY_DESC     CHAR(50)   NOT NULL
    ); -- don't need to specify PRIMARY KEY twice

    --USE COSTUMER RENTAL; -- is there a space in the name or not?

    CREATE TABLE dbo.COSTUME
    (
        Costume_ID              CHAR(5), -- need commas
        Costume_Desc            CHAR(50), 
        Costume_Size            CHAR(5),
        Costume_RentalPricE     DECIMAL(12,2), -- Number isn't a valid SQL Server data type  
        Category_ID             CHAR(5)
    ); -- need closing brackets; also should always use semi-colons to terminate
```

Comment: like i said in description above i want to design a child table with a column "tax", which varies according to price. So my question implicitly is how to design a master table with column "tax" which dishes out values in child table column "tax" with foreign key. thanks for the answer but can you shed somelight on this issue too?